# Ready implementation of multivariate Spearman rank correlation

Tags: python, statistics, correlation

I'm looking for a way to calculate multivariate version of Spearman rank correlation $\rho$. Are there any ready to use Python implementation I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one in [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.stats.stats.html#spearmanr).

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't find the multivariate version of Spearman rank coefficient in scipy. Can you please point me?

Comment: I read too fast and missed the 'multivariate' in your question... There doesn't seem to be any ready implementation on google.

Answer (score 1):

If now or in the future you will want access to some advanced statistical packages, also consider calling R libraries from Python when needed via the [RPy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/index.html).

And then you can compute spearman using a package such as [this](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/S/Harrell/help/Hmisc/html/rcorr.html).